# Enable %-key jumping/highlighting for backticks (`) and single-quotes (') in M4 files

Tags: cursor-motions, highlight, delimiter-matching, jumplist

## Background

When working on `.c` and `.h` files, I have a couple options turned on, namely:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
autocmd BufEnter *.c   setlocal tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 softtabstop=8 textwidth=80 noexpandtab cindent cinoptions=:0,l1,t0,g0,(0
```

This enables a really useful feature for me: when I move the cursor over a bracket (<kbd>`[`</kbd>, <kbd>`]`</kbd>), parenthesis (<kbd>`(`</kbd>, <kbd>`)`</kbd>), or brace (<kbd>`{`</kbd>, <kbd>`}`</kbd>) character, the matching "partner" (assuming my code is syntactically correct) is highlighted, and I can jump between the "partners" via the <kbd>`%`</kbd> key.

---

## Problem

I edit a lot of GNU M4 files, and the most commonly used delimiter/bracket-like characters are the back-tick (<kbd>`` ` ``</kbd>) and single-quote (<kbd>`'`</kbd>) characters. Unfortunately, I cannot highlight and/or jump between pairs like I can with brackets, braces, etc.

---

## Question

1. Is it possible to enable the matching/highlighting/jumping-to-partner features I've described for arbitrary pairs of symbols, assuming that start/stop characters **are not** the same (i.e. backtick and single-quote, in my case)?
2. Is it possible to enable the matching/highlighting/jumping-to-partner features I've described for arbitrary pairs of symbols, assuming that start/stop characters **are** the same (i.e. a pair of double-quotation marks)?
3. Does VI/VIM have the ability to detect escaped symbols, i.e.: could it match a pair of double quotation marks (<kbd>`"`</kbd>), but know to ignore double-quotes with a backslash immediately to the left (i.e. <kbd>`\"`</kbd>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, try this:

```
set matchpairs+=`:'
```

See `:help 'matchpairs'`

This requires the characters to be different, so it won't help you with question 2 (or indeed 3).

For these latter two requirements, the short answer is that Vim doesn't provide this feature by default, and it will be tricky to implement well because it requires a greater understanding of context (and, ideally syntax,) than Vim currently has.

As a related aside, if you want to match things that aren't single characters, see also `:help matchit`.

Comment: This, combined with the `ShowPairs` plugin just made my day a lot easier. I had to increase the max recursion depth of `ShowPairs`, but that's it. Thanks!